# Add another exception to htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, webserver

My .htaccess file alows access to *real* files & folders on the server. For anything else, it will redirect to `/index.php`, *except when* the `app` folder is specified in which case it will redirect to `/app/index.php`. I want to add a **second** folder named `appbeta` which will redirect to `/appbeta/index.php`. How should I modify my .htaccess to add this additional exception?

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!app)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^app(.+)$ /app/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what the following rewrite does:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!app)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

However, if your current `.htaccess` is working as you want, I would try the following which puts a rewrite for `/appbeta` right before the rewrite for `/app`:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!app)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# rewrite /addbeta to /appbeta/index.php ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^appbeta(.*)$ /appbeta/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^app(.+)$ /app/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

note: no new question started as mentioned in comments, fix above (change `^appbeta(.+)$` to `^appbeta(.*)$`)

Comment: the first rewrite says use `/index.php...` *unless* the url matches *app*.... as for your suggestion, I tried but it didn't work. It continues redirecting to app.

Comment: Ah, then lets put the new /appbeta prior to the rule I didn't understand.  I will update the order in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry your original answer was correct. However, there is still the problem of `http://domain.com/appbeta` vs `http://domain.com/appbeta/`.

Comment: @gil I see your update and acknowledge that my error was using the greedy `(.+)` - (ONE or more) instead of the lazy `(.*)` - ZERO or more.